# Is it possible to use php to write in the tables and already use datatable to make tables optimize?

Tags: jquery, datatables, angular-datatables

I have more than one table in one view and i use jquery to make them hide and show.i have the array $works which contains arrays of works.each array contains data that are the rows of each table.
also i use Datatable to optimize my tables using pagination and be able to search.

but it seems `datatables` doesn't know **blade** language and **php**.
i set the datatable to show me in each page 10 row of the table.but when my table has more than 10 rows it shows me all the rows and shows:

```
Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries
```

the above expression.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-7">
<?php $i = 0 ?>
@foreach($works as $work)
        <!--<div class="panel navbar-inverse">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-amir">
                <p href="#">Current Works</p>
            </div>-->
<?php $i+=1; ?>
<div id="{{$dep->id}}" class="panel-body testimonial" data-index="{{$i}}">

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-hover TABLE mytable" id="example" data-index="{{$i}}">
        <thead style="text-align: center">
        <th style="text-align: center">User Works</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Title</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Due Date</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Description</th>
        </thead>

        @foreach($work as $var)
        <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-2">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/amir.png">
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2">
                alaki
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2">
                alaki
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-6">
                alaki
            </td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>
@endforeach
```

[image]

Is there any idea what should i do to design my page correctly????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dataTables only supports *one* `<tbody>` section at a time. You have

```php
@foreach($work as $var)
   <tbody>
     ....
   </tbody>
@endforeach
```

causing multiple `<tbody>`'s, thats why you get *Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries*. Iterate over rows instead :

```html
<tbody>
  @foreach($work as $var)
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-2">
    ...
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

By doing that, I am sure you will get the correct number of rows in the info-section, and the table will paginate as expected.

Comment: thank you so so much.i examined every other complex ways but it was very easy.